# Where does stdout go for a Java Web Start application?

Tags: java, stdout, java-web-start

I'm having troubles with my webstart application and would like to see stdout.  I think it's throwing an exception... but I cannot see it since the console output is hidden somewhere.

How can I get the output of the application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to see Java Exceptions, your user will need to click File -> Preferences -> Advanded Tab and check "Show Java Console"

Comment: In Windows, also: Control Panel -> Java -> Advanced (tab) -> Java Console (radio buttons)

Comment: In Mac OS, run the application Java Preferences.